# Variável executando sozinha

Tags: linux, script, shell-script, shell

Estou tentando criar uma variável que eu vá usar só quando quiser criar uma pasta. Mas essa mesma variável está criando essa pasta antes da condição IF e o do READ serem executados. Segue o exemplo simplificado:

```
#!/bin/bash

criar=$(mkdir API)

echo "Deseja criar a pasta raiz: "
echo "1 - Sim"
echo "2 - Não"
read opcao

if [ $opcao = "1" ]
  then 
      $criar
  else
      echo error
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o `$()`, um substituidor de comandos, irá capturar o valor do comando que você passar dentro e, no seu caso, inserir na variável `criar`. Isso faz com que o comando `mkdir` seja executado durante a declaração daquela variável.

Como você aparentemente quer criar um bloco de código que será executado posteriormente, é ideal criar uma função. No exemplo abaixo, criamos a função `criar`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Definimos a função `criar`:
criar() {
  mkdir API
}

echo "Deseja criar a pasta raiz: "
echo "1 - Sim"
echo "2 - Não"
read opcao

if [ $opcao = "1" ]; then
    criar
  else
    echo "Usuário selecionou: Não."
fi
```

Você pode até criar uma verificação dentro da função, para impedir que o comando `mkdir` seja executado caso o diretório já exista:

```
criar() {
  folder_name="API"

  if [ ! -d "./$folder_name" ]; then
    mkdir $folder_name
  else
    echo "A pasta já existe."
  fi
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.